# How to test if a String contains "__X__", and if so give an alert();

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on Dynamic page where `input#first.val()` is dynamic.

Basically values I'll be getting are either Device Name or Device resolution..

Say if `input#first.val()` is the Device name, like `"iPad"`, then I dont need any further action.

But if `input#first.val()` is the Device resolution, like `"1024 X 768"`, then I want to alert the user.

So how do I detect if `input#first.val()` is the Device resolution?

Also, the Device resolution will be dynamic, so it could look like any of these...

- "**1024 X 768**"
- "**480 X 640**"
- "**320 X 480**"

The common thing will be "**_ X _**"

So how do I detect "**_ X _**" within `input#first.val()` and alert the user?

Maybe with `:contains` and string object?

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="name" value=""/>
```

Comment: Why dont you jsut check it against a regex onChange?

Comment: `:contains`? Please don't make jQuery your first solution for everything. Learn JavaScript.

Comment: I was referring to this for :contains http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ But Yeah !! I'm pretty weak in jQuery..

Comment: @MANnDAaR: Yes, that's what I assumed. Many tasks must be done without jQuery. This is one example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test it with a regular expression:

```
if ($("input#first").val().match(/\d+\s*X\s*\d+/i)) {
    // value contains ddd X ddd
}
```

By way of explanation, this regular expression is:

```
a series of one or more digits
followed by zero or more whitespace elements
followed by an "X" or "x"
followed by zero or more whitespace elements
followed by a series of one or more digits
```

If you want to require that there is nothing else but the resolution numbers, you can use this:

```
if ($("input#first").val().match(/^\d+\s*X\s*\d+$/i)) {
    // value contains ddd X ddd
}
```

If you want to require that each number is at least 3 digits, you can use this:

```
if ($("input#first").val().match(/^\d{3,}\s*X\s*\d{3,}$/i)) {
    // value contains ddd X ddd
}
```

Also, is there any reason to use "input#first" as the selector instead of just "#first"?  The shorter version is less work for the selector engine and since ids must be unique in the page it should generate the same result unless you were somehow trying to filter out a #first that wasn't on an input tag (which seems unlikely).

Comment: Was just testing on regexr when you posted. Damn my poor memory of regex params :)